# How to hide the Id in the URL?

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm using the id of some entities in the URL in order to specify a treatment to a specific element. The routing file is somehow like this:

```
UpdateUser:
    pattern:  /UpdateUser/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AfricaClientBundle:Secteur:UpdateUser }
```

In the URL I get something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/UpdateUser/215
```

This doesn't seem safe at all. Any hint about how to hide it or what to do.

Comment: In my opinion it is perfectly ok to have id in your url as long as you escape the input.

Comment: it is safe. there is a security component in symfony that handle this. read more about how it works http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to show your entities id to your users, either in pages or url, you'll have to define an unique property for each entity, that could be "public".

In an `User` case, typically, you could set the `email` or `username` property `Unique`, and then only  give them in your urls. That way, it is impossible to "farm" your user database by incrementing some id in urls.

This behavior is not only safer but also more pretty and friendly rather having obscur numbers in your urls.

Best

Answer (score 0):

As answered before by @ihsan, using the ID in your URLs is not a security-issue by itself. As an alternative to the ID you could use the [Doctrine Sluggable Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html).
Keep in mind that your parameters still should be unique if you are refering to only one object. Sluggable also provides some SEO advantages.

Answer (score 0):

In this case specifically, if you only want your user to be able to update himself, you should just ommit the `$id` in your URL and read it on your controller from the security.context.

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

This should load the `User` entity from whoever's logged in at the moment. `[...]->getUser()->getId()` should get you the `$id`.

If you don't want this to only work for the UpdateUsuarioAction, want something more generic, you should use `POST` instead of `GET` or maybe ommit the variable completely and store it in the session. Please note using `POST` is not much safer, as the user can modify the `POST` data. It just requires a little bit more work.

Generally, passing an ID is not unsafe, it'll depend on your software's rules.